# Extract date and time from the String "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Tags: java, string, date, time

There is String with the format of "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm". In need to "extract" the date into var1 and the time into var2. Currently I can only format the string into the date.

```
private static Date toDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"); 
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: The question is how to get date and time in two separate variables.

Comment: There is no possibility to fave two different variables with date and time. The `Date` class is a timestamp containing both. If we know what you want to achieve with this variables it could be easier to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Use another `SimpleDateFormat` to format the resultant date into the required date and time `Strings`

```
Date date = toDate(dateString);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = dateFormat.format(date);
dateFormat.applyPattern("HH:mm");
String timeString = dateFormat.format(date);
```